# How to run the function from another file in golang?

Tags: function, go

In this code, I am trying to run the home function in a browser. I made two files, `main.go` and `handler.go`. In `main.go` I called the `handler.Home` function to run it. But it gives me the blank page.

When I take the `Home()` function from the `handler.go` file and use it in `main.go` file, it runs the `Home()` function successfully.

**main.go**

```
package main
 
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/ibilalkayy/WEBAPP1/handler"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler.Home)
    fmt.Println("Starting the server at :8080")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

**handler.go**

```
package handler

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)
var tmpl = make(map[string]*template.Template)

func init() {
    tmpl["home"] = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/home.html", "templates/base.html"))
}

func Home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl["home"].ExecuteTemplate(w, "home.html", nil)
}
```

**main.go only version**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

var tmpl = make(map[string]*template.Template)

func init() {
    tmpl["home"] = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/home.html", "templates/base.html"))
}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl["home"].ExecuteTemplate(w, "home.html", nil)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
    fmt.Println("Starting the server at :8080")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: You can have a quick intro to packages with [go tour](https://tour.golang.org/basics/1)

Comment: Is the `handler.go` file in a separate directory from the one in which in `main.go` lives? And have you imported the `handler` package? Can you show the full `import` in your `main.go` file?

Comment: this is what he is asking... how to create packages and use their code.

Comment: @mkopriva Yes `handler.go` is in another directory.

Comment: Is the `handler.go` supposed to be part of a different package? If no, then change it `package handler` to `package main` and you will have direct access to `Home`.

Comment: @Nick What if I want it to be the part of a different package instead of `package main`

Comment: @sikandarmeranam If, as you claim, the main-only version really works, and the with-hanlder-package version contains no other changes, and compiles, then it should also work. Can you show the working main-only version where you have `Home` implemented in the `main` package, so we can compare and make sure no other important differences are present?

Comment: @sikandarmeranam You might want to add an error check to `ExecuteTemplate` inside `Home` and if the returned `error` value is not `nil` then print it to stdout, it maybe that you've made some changes to the templates which cause it fail.

Comment: @mkopriva I transferred everything from `handler.go` to `main.go` but still does not work and show me blank. I was wrong that it works in `main.go`

Comment: @sikandarmeranam try to add the error check mentioned above, you may get your answer from it.

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you! Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied your code and made a handler package with directory structure like follows.

[image: dir]

It is working as expected.